# facebook4j post from is null

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j

I am using the Facebook API from Java with Facebook4j.

I have two servers, on the one that uses Facebook 2.3 API when I get the from of a post,

```
Post post = connection.getFeed().get(0);
post.getFrom();
```

I get the user, but in the server that uses Facebook 2.4 API, the from is null.

Any idea?  I don't see any documented change in the fb API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [Facebook Platform Changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes), as of v2.4, you now have to manually specify fields if you want them to be retrieved:

> To try to improve performance on mobile networks, Nodes and Edges in
>   v2.4 requires that you explicitly request the field(s) you need for
>   your GET requests. For example, `GET /v2.4/me/feed` no longer includes
>   likes and comments by default, but `GET
>   /v2.4/me/feed?fields=comments,likes` will return the data. For more
>   details see the docs on how to request specific fields.

According to the [docs on `Post`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/post), the relevant field is named `from`.  To request this field in the me feed using Facebook4J, you can use a `Reading` object, as follows:

```
facebook.getFeed(new Reading().fields("from"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  I'm using fields("id", "message", "caption", "description", "created_time", "from") to get all my fields.